# Lax algebras for pseudomonads and monads in Kleisli bicategories for the induced pseudocomonad

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monads, adjoint-functors, 2-categories

In Day–Street's [Lax monoids, pseudo-operads, and convolution](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.611.4194), they remark without proof:

> There are general principles involved here. Suppose $(T, m, j)$ is a pseudomonad on any bicategory $\mathcal K$. If $m : TT \to T$ and $j : 1 \to T$ have right adjoints $m^*$, $j^*$ then we obtain a pseudocomonad $(T, j^*, m^*)$ on $\mathcal K$; moreover, to give a lax algebra for $(T, m, j)$ is to give a monad in the Kleisli bicategory for $(T, j^*, m^*)$.

Is there a reference for this result? Alternatively, if it is folklore, is there a slick proof that avoids having to check the coherence diagrams explicitly?